# Spring Tool Suite(3.6.3.SR1) starter project cannot connect to mongoldb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a very strange problem with my spring starter project:
I am using STS, the version of it is 3.6.3.SR1. I also install mongodb, the version of it is 2.6.7.
I want to use STS to connect to mongodb. So, I tried the project from the tutorial:
File -> new -> Import Spring Getting Started Content. Then I choose "Accessing Data Mongodb". Then I run the gs-accessing-data-mongodb-complete, it worked perfectly. The tutorial is here [enter link description here][1]
However, when I created a spring starter project, the Dependencies I choose MongoDB, Rest Repositories. I copy exactly the same code from above but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

package demo;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Customer {

```
@Id
private String id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Customer() {}

public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
            id, firstName, lastName);
}
```

}

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository {

```
public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
```

}

public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository repository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}


@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    repository.deleteAll();

    // save a couple of customers
    repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
    repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

    // fetch all customers
    System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
        System.out.println(customer);
    }
    System.out.println();

    // fetch an individual customer
    System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

    System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
        System.out.println(customer);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: it seems you have a connection refused exception connecting to the MongodB port, I would try to kill mongodB and start it again and see if that solves the problem, but here is what i see in the exception details, {com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]

Comment: I am using the default port 27017, STS is also using the default port 27017,  I use terminal to connect to it, it worked perfectly. The strange thing is when I use STS starter project, it is not working:(.

Comment: I think my problem is how to use spring starter project to connect to Mongodb, because all the "Import Spring Getting Started Content" works perfectly for me

Comment: I have a project that connects to MongodB but I compile using gradle from the commandline, I just created a project in STS and used the same code to connect to MongodB and no issues, post the code that you are using to connect MongodB and maybe your gradle.build if you are using gradle or pom.xml if you are using maven, I maybe able to detect the issue

Comment: I just update it. It is really strange

Comment: by the way, in my main class I did add the annotation, including ComponentScan
Configuration
EnableMongoRepositories
Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
EnableAutoConfiguration
SpringBootApplication

Comment: everything looks good, but from your last comment, I would think you may need to comment out all of the items you listed and see if you connect to the database, then see which one is causing the issue by adding them one by one.  I have a feeling it is the EnableMongoRepositories, but I could be wrong, I have never used it before

Comment: I will try your way and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: However, I try the same thing on a different mac, it works perfectly. It is really strange.

Comment: If that is the case that it works fine on one computer and not on the other, then I think you have another process tying up the port number based on the connect exception, try to restart the computer and see if that solves the problem.